# expand a div (on hover) on top of another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, expand, onhover

How to expand a div (on hover) on top of another div?
How I can do something like is showed in the attached picture?

```
<article>
    <header>
        content title
    </header>
    <div>
        main article content
    </div>
    <div class="share_buttons">
        <div class="">SHARE</div>
        <div class="share_in">
            <a>FACEBOOK</a>
            <a>GOOGLE+</a>
            <a>LINKEDIN</a>
            <a>PICASA</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

[image: Expand div]

Comment: Please share your CSS, or even better, create a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem. On what element do you trigger the hover, and how are they all placed?

Comment: As is always the case with this kind of thing, get the positioning figured out first, and then worry about hovering. Are you asking how to position the divs one over the other? Or how to adjust the positing/visibility on hover?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here, I made one from scratch, the whole thing, but is has a different (and better) HTML layout, and it also uses pure CSS, no JavaScript required.

`EDIT 1` Updated JSFiddle Better example & Better CSS layout.

HTML

```
<div class='box'>
    <div class='box-cnt'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicunt perpetua te mei. Vis id tritani utroque copiosae...</div>

    <div class='box-share'>
        <div class='share-title'>Share</div>
        <div class='share-items'>
            <div class='item'>Facebook</div>
            <div class='item'>Google</div>
            <div class='item'>MySpace</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    position: relative;
}

.box-share {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: height 450ms;
    -moz-transition: height 450ms;
    -webkit-transition: height 450ms;
}

    .box-share:hover {
        height: 100px;
    }

.share-title {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3.2;
}

.share-items {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.box-cnt {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.item {display: inline-block;height: 100%;margin: 5px;}
```

Here is an example [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE6uT/13/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS [Pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) selector [:hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Try this:

```
article:hover .share_in
{
    display:block;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6DPz/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first display:none; the share links. then you can use that

```
$( "#div-selector" ).onhover(function() {
    $( "#share-link" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the div element position once hover, which i guess its :

```
<div class="share_buttons">
```

also, for that case its probably best to set an id for the element and not a class as this is a unique for that element only .

so you could set the position attribute to absolute and change the margin / padding css attributes,

That's an option, there are more.. you should play with it, the idea is that the whole time the whole div is there and you just reveal / un-reveal it .

Answer (score 0):

Use **[hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** for the hover effect, and **[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** to get the sliding effect.

```
$('.share_buttons').hover(function(){

    $('.share_in').animate("...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if I'm getting it right you want the "share_buttons" div to slide up on hover and slide down on mouse out! if so you have to note that the position of "share_buttons" div must be absolute, relative or fixed! if it is so, this is the code to do it:

```
$(.share_buttons).hover(function(){
    addedHeight='the height that you want it to grow to e.g. 100px';
    $(this).animate({
        height:addedHeight,
        marginTop:'-'+addedHeight
    },500);
},function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height:'the default height',
        marginTop:0
    },500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remember, XXpx is the height of div.share_in, in pixels.
It would be better if you had created a fiddle.

```
$( ".share_buttons" ).hover ( function() {
    $( ".share_in" ).animate( { "height" : "XXpx" } );
}, function() {
    $( ".share_in" ).animate( { "height" : "0px" } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.main_content').hover(function(){         $('.share_buttons').slideDown('slow',500);      },
    function(){         $('.share_buttons').slideUp('slow',500);      }
);
```